# Implementation of Splash screen with the help of Touch Events

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am following [This Tutorial](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-40-implement-splash-screen-in-android/) of implementing splash screen in my android project and i want splash screen is closed whenever user tap two time on screen. If this can be done using touch events then how i used them ?

Comment: just want to let you know: http://wptheming.com/2010/01/splash-screens-are-bad/ http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Comment: thanks for the useful information Tyler but sometime you need to implement such things those even harm your.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to take a look at 'onInterceptTouch' from there you can 'finish();' as usual

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29
```

You could also set the LinearLayouts **android:clickable="true"**

and then use an onclicklistner

```
final LinearLayout MYLAYOUT = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MYLAYOUT);
    MYLAYOUT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

You might also have to add **android:duplicateParentState="true"** to all the views INSIDE your linear Layout

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to use a gesturedetector.

Add an id to your splash LinearLayout so that you can get a reference to it in code

Then in onCreate of MainActivity you'll need to do:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
...
LinearLayout splashBg = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.splash_bg);
GestureListener mGestureListener = new GestureListener();
GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, mGestureListener);
splashBg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
}//end onCreate
```

You'll need to create this custom GestureListener to listen for the double tap and then close the splash and continue to the next activity

```
private class GestureListener implements GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            MainActivity.this.finish();

            if (!mIsBackButtonPressed) {
                 // start the home activity 
                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                 MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to set splashscreen

```
 int touchcount=0;
 LinearLayout layout;
 layout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
 layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      touchevent++;
                         if(touchcount==2)
                             {
                               Intent intent=new Intent(youractivity,this,nextactivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
                              }

            return false;

        }
    });
```